# How to access storage?

Tags: android, android-storage

The most intuitive seems to be `Environment.getStorageDirectory()`. However, it's red in Android Studio with a warning that the call requires Api level R (min is 16). I'm certainly not going to raise the minimum Api to 30 (= R)! Still, my App runs in the emulator with Android 7.1.1 and I can list the contents of that directory. How is that possible?

Then there is `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`, which is deprecated. I'd still use it though, if it's still the recommended approach in 2021. I didn't get how to access an external sdcard or an USB stick with this method though. Despite its name, it only seems to grant access to the internal emulated sdcard.

I also found `File.listRoots()`, which returns `"/"`. But `File.listRoots()[0]` or `File("/")` are both `null`. What am I missing here? Why can't I access the file system that way?

There are some other methods in `Environment` and `Context`, but as far as I can tell they only grant access to some special directory. I want to access the whole file system, and all block devices,  like in a File Explorer App.

Comment: "I want to access the whole file system, and all block devices, like in a File Explorer App" -- outside of rooted devices, there is no file explorer app that has access to the whole filesystem. "Why can't I access the file system that way?" -- because you do not have permission to access `/`. "I didn't get how to access an external sdcard or an USB stick with this method though" -- that is not really an option on most versions of Android.

Comment: "it only seems to grant access to the internal emulated sdcard" -- it grants access to [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/10/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html). "Still, my App runs in the emulator with Android 7.1.1 and I can list the contents of that directory. How is that possible?" -- I think that function has been there for a long time, just perhaps not exposed in the Android SDK. You might want to review [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data) on data storage, or your preferred book on Android app development.

Comment: And, if you really want to try to implement a file explorer, there are many open source ones that you can use as a foundation, such as [this](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/me.zhanghai.android.files/) and [this](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/com.simplemobiletools.filemanager.pro/).

Comment: Have a look at all the items returned by getExternalFilesDirs(). It will give you paths on external storage, removable micro sd card and often usb otg drives. If the latter is not mentioned then use storage accesd framework to access it. SAF can be used for all three too.

Comment: @CommonsWare: thanks for the link to your blog, that article (and the others in the series) were very informative. The situation is a lot worse than I thought!